# How to solve TOP 'n' FOR EACH 'entity' in MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new in Hadoop/MR world and trying to solve the following problem:

A college is trying to find it top 20 subjects offered in the past 20 years based on it popularity. The program should find out the top 20 subjects by counting the number of visit by unique students at each of its campuses. Ideal output should be like this:

```
Campus1 Mathes:3500 Law:3200 JavaProg:2830 Anatomy:2701 ...
Campus2 DB:4200 Chamistry:4190 Business:3999 Astronomy:3500 ...
Campus3 C/C++:2800 Python:2799 BigData:1900 WebDev:1200 ...
...
...
```

There are two files that contains different but relevant datasets:

```
subjects.txt & students.txt
```

`subjects.txt` contains all information about the subject and student id which is details `students.txt` file which means the to file must be inner joined in order to find out the popularity.

Since this is involves multiple files and multiple MR jobs which is going to be chained. Please advice on how to implement a solution for this problem.

****EDIT:****

Subject.txt:

```
Subj_id \t Subj_name \t Location_offered \t Stdnt_id \t Semstr_offered \t Instructor_id
```

Student.txt:

```
stdnt_id \t stdnt_name \t dob \t campus \t year_of_start
```

Comment: Will you be able to post some contents of subjects.txt & students.txt. How the data look like in these files.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have to find out top 20 subjects by the students visits counts at every campus of the college.

If so , then the required fields would be location offered , subj_name,  stdnt_id. These 3 columns will be enough to derive the expected results. So you may only use the subjects.txt and skip the join process.

**Stage 1:**

In this job, the processing is similar as wordcount. Parse the campus id, subject id from the subject.txt file, and create key by concating caumpus id and subject id, and put 1 as value. At reducer for every key do the sum of all values.

The result of this phase will be

campus1&Maths : 3500

campus2&Chemistry : 4190

campus1&Law:3200 .......

This results contain the visit count for every subject on every campus, but unordered.

**Stage 2:-**

In this stage, Use secondary sorting to emit only top 20 records for each campus.

Create a composite key with Campus_id , subject id and visit count . Create the sort comparator and partitioner to use the campus id and  create the grouping comparator to sort the keys on visit count in descending order.

At the reducer method use an incrementer variable upto 20 and emit the results.Exit from the loop once after exeeding 20. within this 20 iteration, prepare a String or any array to represent the details about the campus/subject/visits to be emitted as result.

Refer the http://codingjunkie.net/secondary-sort/ for secondary sorting.